# find volume of area under a slope

Tags: calculus

[image]

[image]

Find volume under a slope in a cylindrical structure.

I have a grain bin that has grain in a sloped configuration.

The diameter of bin is 17.9 feet.
The top height measures 13.3 feet
The bottom height measures 10 feet.

What is the volume of the area under the slope.  Assume slope is linear.

This is a real life problem. I have a picture.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine cloning the desired region, then flipping it around so that the two regions stack on top of each other to form a cylinder of radius $r = \frac{d}{2}$ and height $h = h_1 + h_2$. Then the desired volume is half that of the new cylinder:
$$
V
= \tfrac{1}{2}\pi r^2 h
= \tfrac{1}{2}\pi (\tfrac{d}{2})^2 (h_1 + h_2)
= \tfrac{1}{2}\pi (\tfrac{17.9}{2})^2 (13.3 + 10.0)
= 2931.72...
$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the volume under the sloped part. This is found using $\pi \big(\frac{d}{2}\big)^2 \cdot h_2 $. The volume of the sloped part is half of the volume needed to fill up the bin flatly. Hence, it is $\frac{\Big(\pi (\frac{d}{2}\big)^2 \cdot h_1-h_2\Big)}{2} $. Plug in $h_1$, $h_2$ and $d$ to find the total volume under the slope.